# Geo Intent, how to auto launch directions

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, geolocation, direction

Currently developing Ionic mobile app and have a get directions button on one of the pages.

Currently setting my intent like this

```
if(address.length !== 0){
    address = "(" + address + ")";
}
var location = getDrivingLocation();
var url = encodeURI(location.latitude + "," + location.longitude + "?q=" + location.latitude + "," + location.longitude + address);
window.location = "geo:" + url + "&z=18";
```

It launches the map and current spot, but I still need to press the get directions button manually on google maps to start directions. Is there anything in the URL that I can change to make it auto start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a URL scheme, URL scheme allows you to launch an IOS application from another IOS app. These are the supported URL schemes:

- comgooglemaps:// and comgooglemaps-x-callback:// - These schemes allow you to launch the Google Maps app for iOS and perform one of several actions:

  - Display a map at a specified location and zoom level.
  - Search for locations or places, and display them on a map.
  - Request directions from one location to another. Directions can be returned for four modes of transportation: driving, walking, bicycling and public transit.
  - Add navigation to your app.
- comgooglemapsurl:// - This scheme allows you to launch the Google Maps app for iOS using a URL derived from the desktop Google Maps website. This means that you can give your users a native mobile experience rather than simply loading the Google Maps website.

For more information you can check this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme#overview).

I don't know if this is what you want, but you can check this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple). I think it will give you some idea.